# About is not working in My Ubuntu App for desktop

Tags: 12.04, application-development, gtk

I have developed the same app "mybrowser" told by [Jono Bacon in his tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sO8hiPreNBg). But when I want to see About it is throwing the following error:

```
Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py:391: Warning: g_object_set_property: construct property "type" for object `AboutDialog' can't be set after construction

Gtk.Window.__init__(self, type=type, **kwds)

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/navneet/Apps/Ubuntu apps/mybrowser/mybrowser_lib/Window.py", line 85, in on_mnu_about_activate
    about = self.AboutDialog() # pylint: disable=E1102

  File "/home/navneet/Apps/Ubuntu apps/mybrowser/mybrowser_lib/AboutDialog.py", line 21, in __new__

    new_object.finish_initializing(builder)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'finish_initializing'
```